# How to bind checkbox checked values to List<int> in Viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to post list of integers from view to controller using model binding. I don't want to use Html helper methods. I want to use HTML tags only.

ViewModel:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public List<int> CheckboxValues { get; set; }
}
```

CSHTML:

```
<form action = "Controller/Action" method="POST">
 <label>                                                                                                                    
    <input name="CheckboxValues" value="1" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 1</span>
    <input name="CheckboxValues" value="2" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 2</span>
    <input name="CheckboxValues" value="3" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 3</span>                                                                                                             </label>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px; height:30px;" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult ActionMethod(MyClass data)
    {
        /* ... Here I'm getting **data.CheckboxValues** as Null*/
    }
```

I have used the same name as that of my ViewModel has. I'm still getting the null value in my controller.

Comment: Why don't you want to use HTML Helper methods?

Comment: @SidharthaSankarPrusty If you found a solution, please share it. If you used any of the provided answers, please mark one as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

`CheckboxValues` is a `List<T>`, it needs to be indexed in the `name` property of each checkbox element for it to post the data correctly to the server. Please see updated markup below. Also, if you aren't going to use "hidden" elements to pass back the true/false of your checkboxes, you would need to change the value property in your markup to hold "true/false" and not integer values. Your model List may also need changed to reflect the boolean type instead of integer. The integer value you are currently setting in your markup can be inferred by the index of your (list + 1). You'd need some kind of front end code to change the `value` property of your checkboxes on `change` or `click` so that they are set appropriately.

```
<!--the name properties would look like below, but the value properties don't reflect boolean-->  
<input name="CheckboxValues[0]" value="1" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 1</span>
<input name="CheckboxValues[1]" value="2" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 2</span>
<input name="CheckboxValues[2]" value="3" type="checkbox"> <span class="label-text">Choice 3</span>
```

I would suggest these changes:

MODEL:

```
//Change to List<bool> to reflect true/false values of the front end
public List<bool> CheckboxValues { get; set; }
```

HTML Markup (CSHTML):

```
@model MyClass

<!--value property starts as false and will change accordingly on checkbox change/click event added a class to add event handling-->
<input name="CheckboxValues[0]" value="false" type="checkbox" class="chkChoice"> <span class="label-text">Choice 1</span>
<input name="CheckboxValues[1]" value="false" type="checkbox" class="chkChoice"> <span class="label-text">Choice 2</span>
<input name="CheckboxValues[2]" value="false" type="checkbox" class="chkChoice"> <span class="label-text">Choice 3</span>
```

Javascript to update value of checkboxes:

```
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chkChoice');
for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       if(this.checked){
          this.value = "true";
       }else {
          this.value = "false";
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting null value

Comment: @SidharthaSankarPrusty Did you Model bind at the top of your `.cshtml` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom ValueProvider, ValueProviderFactory

video(no audio) :
https://vimeo.com/433647792

source code:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AhL37xItyntOBpb0s24tjAq3lxQjGBjvtlQ/

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts in solving the issue. However, I figured out another way of solving it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can try to call TryUpdateModel() in action.